# Proper way to get attribute from json

Tags: php, json, decoding

```
 <?php
         $json_string = file_get_contents('infile.json');
         $get_json_values=json_decode($json_string,true);

            foreach ($get_json_values as $key=>$getlikes) {  
              if($getlikes[$key]['type']=='like') {

              ?>
              <div><p><?php echo $getlikes['name'] ?></p></div>
            <?php
          }}
           ?>
```

There is an error in the code above: undefined offset on the line with the if. I guess it is because `$getlikes[$key]['type']` is wrong. What would be the proper code to get all the objects with the `type` attribute  being "like"?

Json can be downloaded from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gtqrzml1p9p5zpy/infile.json)

Comment: Please show your JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really depends on the content of your .json object. But most likely the undefined offset is being caused because not all $getlikes[$key] has an array key of 'type'. Validate to make sure it exists before you compare. Try

```
foreach ($get_json_values as $key=>$getlikes) { 
    if(!isset($getlikes['type'])) continue;
        if($getlikes['type']=='like') {
    ....
```

EDIT:

Based on your .json file you were just adding an additional key which was unneeded. Changed the code to reflect the correct call. Still not a bad idea to check if a value is set. Try a var_dump($getlikes) or on the file you are using to get a good look at what you are iterating over.

Comment: doesn't show anything anymore, but all of them have the key "type". I uploaded the json

Comment: Edited my answer to the correct iteration. You used $getlikes[$key] and you probably meant to use $get_json_values[$key]

Answer (score 1):

Given the JSON string it's clear what you're doing wrong. $get_json_values is a list with no indexes, you're doubling up on the key, hard to explain. Do this instead.

```
foreach ($get_json_values as $getlikes) { 
    if($getlikes['type']=='like') {
```

If you were to use $key, you'd use it like this

```
foreach ($get_json_values as $key=>$getlikes) { 
    if($get_json_values[$key]['type']=='like') {
```

but you wouldn't do that anyway. Foreach extracts the elements one by one.